# How to set default selected value in UX Symfony dropdown

Tags: symfony, stimulusjs, tom-select, ux-symfony

I managed to implement dropdown with UX Symphony using custom Autocompleter following the [documentation](https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-autocomplete/current/index.html#advanced-creating-an-autocompleter-with-no-form).

```
namespace App\Autocompleter;

class FooAutocompleter implements EntityAutocompleterInterface { ... }
```

I add this view :

```
<select name="foo"
     {{ stimulus_controller('symfony/ux-autocomplete/autocomplete', {
        url: path('ux_entity_autocomplete', { alias: 'foo' })
     }) }}></select>
```

I would like to know how to set default selected value using this tool ( UX Symfony / Tom Select / Stimulus ) ?